# how to loop a dynamic array containing multiple dynamic nested arrays

Tags: php, json

I have a dynamic array containing several dynamic nested arrays. I want to iterate each and every element in that root array.

Example:

```
     $obj = new stdClass(){
        [children] => [
           {
             id:1,
             [children] : [
                {
                  id: 2,
                  children : []
                },
                {
                  id: 3,
                  children : [
                    {
                      id: 15,
                      children : []
                    }
                  ]
                }
             ]
           },
           {
             id:4,
             [children] : [
                {
                  id: 5,
                  children : [
                    {
                      id: 16,
                      children : []
                    },
                  ]
                },
                {
                  id: 6,
                  children : []
                },
                {
                  id: 7,
                  children : [
                    {
                      id: 17,
                      children : []
                    },
                  ]
                },
                {
                  id: 8,
                  children : []
                }
             ]
           },
           {
             id:9,
             [children] : [
                 {
                  id: 10,
                  children : [
                    {
                      id: 11,
                      children : []
                    },
                    {
                      id: 12,
                      children : []
                    },
                    {
                      id: 13,
                      children : [
                        {
                          id: 14,
                          children : []
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                  ]
                }
             ]
           }
        ]
     }
```

Can somebody help? I want to store them in the same way, for that, I need to loop the root node, parent node, child node, etc. I want all childs to be in their respective parent nodes.

Comment: It is unclear what it exactly is you want to do. You say: _"I want to store them"_, but what does that mean? Also, if you show us what you have already tried, then that might shed some light on your intentions.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want to copy this array of objects to another object

Comment: OK, then you can use `$otherObj = $obj` or `$otherObj = clone $obj`. See; [Object Cloning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware actually i can't use this bcz, there are many properties in these objects. I want few of them.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i need to traverse each and every element via loop or recursion

Comment: Ok. So what's preventing you from doing that, exactly? What have you tried, what went wrong? Have you researched any existing techniques? "I want" / "I need" isn't a question or a clear problem statement, and we're not a free write-my-code service. You need to show a good-faith attempt to investigate and code (at least some of) it yourself, and identify a specific thing in your code that you're stuck on. Don't just (implictly or explicitly) ask us to provide you a ready-made solution, or request unspecific "help", that's not how this site works. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Also if you only want to get specific properties from the data, then a) that's not what you said in your question, and b) you need to give a clear example of the starting data, and then the output you want to get at the end, and any business logic which might needed in order to determine which items to use and which to ignore. Otherwise we have no real idea what the requirement is.